# How can I access the json key value with help of typescript variable?

Tags: json, angular, typescript, ionic-framework

****Json File****

```
"Tamil": {
  "Name": "பெயர்",
  "Email": "மின்னஞ்சல்",
  "Phoneno": "தொலைபேசி எண்",
  "Password": "கடவுச்சொல்",
  "CPassword": "கடவுச்சொல்லை உறுதிப்படுத்தவும்",
  "Register": "பதிவு",
  "Cancel": "ரத்துசெய்"

},
```

**Ts File**

```
import {Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import * as data from '../home/lang.json';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['home.page.scss'],
})
export class HomePage implements OnInit {
  public language;
  public value;

  constructor() {
    this.value = 'Tamil';
    this.language = data[this.value].Name;
    alert(this.language);
  }

  ngOnInit() {

  }
}
```

**Output**

```
ERROR Error: "Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: _home_lang_json__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_2___namespace[this.value] is undefined
HomePage@http://localhost:8100/home-home-module.js:128:9
HomePage_Factory@ng:///HomePage/ɵfac.js:5:10
```

> But When I try this possibility is working fine:

this.language = data["Tamil"].Name;

> But while trying this

this.language = data[this.value].Name;
It's Showing that error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only mistake you are doing is accessing Malayalam which does not exist in your JSON file, add Malayalam and it will work fine.

Some code fine tune I am doing which might help.

**replace**

`import * as data from '../home/lang.json'`

**to** coz TypeScript > 2.9 has a simplest way to do that

`import data from '../home/lang.json`

**JSON File**

```
{
  "Tamil": {  
    "Name":       "பெயர்",   
    "Email":      "மின்னஞ்சல்",   
    "Phoneno":    "தொலைபேசி எண்"  ,
    "Password":     "கடவுச்சொல்",
    "CPassword": "கடவுச்சொல்லை உறுதிப்படுத்தவும்",
    "Register":"பதிவு",
    "Cancel" :  "ரத்துசெய்"
},
  "Malayalam": {
    "Name":       "பெயர் m",   
    "Email":      "மின்னஞ்சல் m",   
    "Phoneno":    "தொலைபேசி எண் m"  ,
    "Password":     "கடவுச்சொல் m",
    "CPassword": "கடவுச்சொல்லை உறுதிப்படுத்தவும் m",
    "Register":"பதிவு m",
    "Cancel" :  "ரத்துசெய் m"
 }
}
```

**Component**

```
constructor() {
  this.value = "Malayalam";
  this.language = data[this.value].Name;
  alert(this.language)
}
```

Hope this works.

Answer (score 0):

You can make on `http` call to fetch the json data

```
constructor(
        private httpClient: HttpClient
    ) { }

this.httpClient.get('../home/lang.json')
  .subscribe((res) => {
     this.data = res;
 });
```

Or simply you can read the file as

```
this.data= require('../home/lang.json');
```

Comment: Never do this, no need to read JSON data using http and subscribe.

Comment: Can you please explain me the reason for not making the http call for this.

Comment: Checkout my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

The dynamic import returns Promise.
use case:

```
import * as data from '../home/lang.json'

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['home.page.scss'],
})
export class HomePage implements OnInit {
  public language;
  public value;
  constructor() {
    this.value = "Malayalam";
    this.language = data.default <=== add `default`
    [this.value]?.Name;
    alert(this.language)
  }
  ngOnInit() {

  }
}
```

You can print `data` in the console to see its structure.

Comment: Sorry, its not a dynamic import.

Answer (score 0):

[CheckThis](https://stackblitz.com/edit/input-ngmodel-uy2mer)

You can the value by

```
 this.result =this.data[this.language].Name
```

Sample code

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: 
    `<input [(ngModel)]="language" (ngModelChange)="onSelection()" > 
    <h1>{{ result ? result : data[language].Name }}</h1>`,
})
export class AppComponent  {
  language = 'Tamil';
  result='';

   public data = {
    "Tamil": {  
              "Name":       "பெயர்",   
              "Email":      "மின்னஞ்சல்",   
              "Phoneno":    "தொலைபேசி எண்"  ,
              "Password":     "கடவுச்சொல்",
              "CPassword": "கடவுச்சொல்லை உறுதிப்படுத்தவும்",
              "Register":"பதிவு",
              "Cancel" :  "ரத்துசெய்" 
    }  ,
     "Malayalam": {  
              "Name":       "Name Malayalam",   
              "Email":      "Email malayalam",   
              "Phoneno":    "தொலைபேசி எண்"  ,
              "Password":     "கடவுச்சொல்",
              "CPassword": "கடவுச்சொல்லை உறுதிப்படுத்தவும்",
              "Register":"பதிவு",
              "Cancel" :  "ரத்துசெய்" 
    }  
   }

onSelection() {
this.result =this.data[this.language].Name
  }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you forgot to add Malayalam language in your json.

If it can be happen that language may not present in your json then you should do like this

```
this.language = data[this.value] ? data[this.value].Name : '';
```

Instead of blank you can use default language too. If defualt language available in your json file then you can use like this.

```
this.language = data[this.value] ? data[this.value].Name : data['defaultLanguage'].Name ;
```